# React Package is not getting loaded from node-modules

Tags: reactjs, installation, package

I have created the package for learning purpose **nik-drop** presently available in npm.

now testing purpose I tried to use that package in my another demo project but when I try to use this package from npm-moduls. I unable to access that package.

Even through Package is available in node-module folder.

```
import DropDownMob from 'nik-drop';
```

I'm getting error

Module not found: Can't resolve 'nik-drop' in '/home/nikhil/Documents/React-Project/sec/sec/src'

This is not node module path, react trying to access it from local directory.

How can I resolve it.

Comment: Have you installed this package using `npm` / `yarn`? Is `package.json` file contains entry for `nik-drop`?

Comment: You lib seems not packaged in the right way: https://unpkg.com/nik-drop - you are referring probably to a `main` entry in package.json which is not there

Comment: @keul this means I have not published correctly ?

Comment: That's mean that this release is broken. Check your package.json. BTW: I'm not sure this is the issue you have, but it's something to be fixed

Comment: @ravibagul91 entry present in package.json and even folder is also present.

Comment: @keul index.js present in src/index.js

Comment: https://unpkg.com/nik-drop@0.1.3/src/index.js

Comment: As I said: fix the `main` entry in `package.json` to point to your entry point (commonly _not_ the one in `src` but in the build directory). See https://nodesource.com/blog/the-basics-of-package-json-in-node-js-and-npm/ - with no `main` specified it's trying to load an "index.js" on your package root